# Exact same file path but different content

Tags: php, windows, file

I have a REALLY strange thing happening! When I view a file (within the "Program Files (x86)" folder tree) in my file manager it has one content, but when I retrieve it through PHP CLI script using `file_get_contents()` it has different content (with some additional lines I added through the script earlier) - except if I run the CLI script in a prompt with admin rights, then I see the same content. How on earth is it possible that the same file can have different content based on the permissions of the user accessing the file? **Is that really possible, and if so where can I find more information on how it works?** I've never heard of such a thing in my 25+ years of computing and programming experience...

I have quatro-checked that the path is the same and checked in all kinds of ways that there isn't something else playing a trick on me - but I just can't find any possible explanations!

I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: So what do you want from us? Do you want confirmation? Because well, I cannot do that, how to put it.. lightly.. Missing a few snippets of code? Who is to say your code is not at fault in this scenario?

Comment: As I said I want to know if it's possible to have different content based on permissions. The script does nothing but retrieve the file content with file_get_contents(). Could it be some broken caching mechanism in PHP, a bug simply?!

Comment: UAC Virtualization.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681

Comment: ... which means that either your file manager or the build of PHP you are using doesn't have a manifest declaring compatibility with Windows Vista.

Comment: ... probably PHP come to think of it, since it created the files in question and shows you different results depending on whether it has admin rights.  Did you build this instance of PHP yourself?  I'd be unpleasantly surprised if the official Windows builds were this out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32-bit applications that do not have a `requestedExecutionLevel` node in their [manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191.aspx) are assumed to be [UAC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.06.uac.aspx)-unaware and if they try to write to a privileged location in the file system or registry (when the process is not elevated) the write operation is [virtualized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756960.aspx). Virtualized files are stored in `%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore`.

Manually delete the file in the virtual store and then edit the ACL/security of the file if you need to write to it from your script as a standard user...

Comment: Oh my, that's exactly what had happened. Had no idea of this behaviour! I would rather have the write/read fail than doing this virtualization but maybe that's not an option...